# Unable to apply foreach loop properly in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I want two posts at each slide. but getting only one slide. I am new in programming, please help me.

```
$widget_id  = $widget->id.'-'.uniqid();
    $settings   = $widget->settings;
    $navigation = array();
    $captions   = array();

    $i = 0;
?>

<div id="slideshow-<?php echo $widget_id; ?>" class="wk-slideshow wk-slideshow-revista-articles" data-widgetkit="slideshow" data-options='<?php echo json_encode($settings); ?>'>
    <div>
        <ul class="slides">

            <?php foreach ($widget->items as $key => $item) : ?>
            <?php
                $navigation[] = '<li><span></span></li>';
                $captions[]   = '<li>'.(isset($item['caption']) ? $item['caption']:"").'</li>';

                /* Lazy Loading */
                $item["content"] = ($i==$settings['index']) ? $item["content"] : $this['image']->prepareLazyload($item["content"]);
            ?>
            <li>
                <article class="wk-content clearfix"><?php echo $item['content']; ?></article>
            </li>
            <?php $i=$i+1;?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php if ($settings['buttons']): ?><div class="next"></div><div class="prev"></div><?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo ($settings['navigation'] && count($navigation)) ? '<ul class="nav">'.implode('', $navigation).'</ul>' : '';?>
        <div class="caption"></div><ul class="captions"><?php echo implode('', $captions);?></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy1ih.png

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `{` after the `foreach` and at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`$settings['index']` never changes within the loop, however `$i` does.
Change to: `($i<2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($widget->items as $key => $item) { 

            $navigation[] = '<li><span></span></li>';
            $captions[]   = '<li>'.(isset($item['caption']) ? $item['caption']:"").'</li>';

            /* Lazy Loading */
            $item["content"] = ($i==$settings['index']) ? $item["content"] : $this['image']->prepareLazyload($item["content"]);
        ?>
        <li>
            <article class="wk-content clearfix"><?php echo $item['content']; ?></article>
        </li>
        <?php 
         $i=$i+1;
         }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach syntax looks fine. That syntax is a lot easier for some people to read when embedded in HTML than the traditional braces.

Can I ask what the **$this** variable refers to? I don't see this instantiated anywhere in your code? Is it supposed to be **$item** instead?